# FileStream.WriteLine() is not writing to file

Tags: c#, file-io, stream, text-files

I am trying to make a simple software which stores data in a TXT log file.
This is my code

```
FileStream fs = null;
StreamWriter fw = null;
try
{
    fs= new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)+"/textme.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    fw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    fw.Write("sadadasdsadsadsadas");

    for (int i = 0; i < AnimalShelter.AnimalList.Count; i++)
    {
        fw.WriteLine("<chipNr>" + AnimalShelter.AnimalList[i].ChipRegistrationNumber + "<chipNr>");
        Console.WriteLine("<chipNr>" + AnimalShelter.AnimalList[i].ChipRegistrationNumber + "<chipNr>");
    }
}
catch(IOException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR THROWN");
}
finally
{
    if (fs!= null) fs.Close();
    //  if (fw != null) fw.Close();
}
```

What I achieved is: the file gets created, but nothing gets written in it. 
I checked a lot of posts but I could not find any particular help.

Comment: First of all, the try/finally blocks are not needed, you can use a `using` block instead.

Comment: you may need to flush the StreamWriter: `fw.Flush()`

Comment: StreamWriter has a constructor that takes a string, the path to the file, and a bool, set to true to append.  It would have helped you to fall in the pit of success.

Comment: You need to flush AND Close the stream to ensure all data is written. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.close.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Adding a call to `Flush` the stream works.  This is because you are wrapping the `FileStream`.  `StreamWriter` will write to the `FileStream`, but you need to indicate when to send the `Stream` to the actual file.  Also, you can exchange your `try finally` with a `using`:

```
try
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)+"/textme.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (var fw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            fw.Write("sadadasdsadsadsadas");

            for (int i = 0; i < AnimalShelter.AnimalList.Count; i++)
            {
                fw.WriteLine("<chipNr>" + AnimalShelter.AnimalList[i].ChipRegistrationNumber + "<chipNr>");
                Console.WriteLine("<chipNr>" + AnimalShelter.AnimalList[i].ChipRegistrationNumber + "<chipNr>");

            }
            fw.Flush(); // Added
        }
    }
}
catch(IOException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR THROWN");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Enclose your `StreamWriter` in an using block to be sure that everything is correctly closed at the end of the file usage, also I don't think you need to create a `FileStream` for this to work.

```
try
{
    string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "textme.txt")
    using(fw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
    {
         ......
    }
}
catch(IOException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR THROWN");
}
```

Note that the `StreamWriter` has a constructor that accepts two parameters, the name of the file to create/open and a flag to indicate that the file should be opened in append mode or overwritten
[See StreamWriter docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Always use `using` (as mentioned already) and you won't run into problems (or have to think about it)...

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/textme.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
using (StreamWriter fw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    fw2.Write("sadadasdsadsadsadas");
}
```

(also you could have closed the writer instead of filestream which should've worked)

The problem is as I far as I can tell...

`FileStream.Close` is actually `Stream.Close` - and that calls `Dispose` but it ain't virtual, so does some general cleanup.

`FileStream.Dispose` which is called implicitly when you use `using` - does specific `Flush` and then `Close`/Dispose - so does proper specific cleanup.

You can avoid any of that via `using` as that is generally recommended pattern (and frankly never got me into any of these)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Flush() is the answer; however, I would use [`File.WriteAllLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines.aspx) instead.

```
try
{
    var fileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)+"/textme.txt";
    var lines = AnimalShelter.AnimalList.Select(o=> "<chipNr>" + o.ChipRegistrationNumber + "</chipNr>");
    File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
    foreach(var line in lines)
        Console.WriteLine(line);
}
catch(IOException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR THROWN");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this - just replace the array:

```
try
{
    using (Stream fs = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/textme.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            int[] test = new int[] { 0, 12, 23, 46 };
            sw.Write("sadadasdsadsadsadas");
            for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("<chipNr>" + test[i] + "<chipNr>");
                Console.WriteLine("<chipNr>" + test[i] + "<chipNr>");
            }
            sw.Close();                    
        }
        fs.Close();
    } 

}
catch (IOException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR THROWN");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As codechops mentioned, close() worked for me. I had issue with last write, and using close() of file stream fixed the issue.

Basically data from the stream needs to be flushed onto the file, for write to work properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).